# Template system in CodeIgniter like wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, codeigniter

I'm trying to build a template system in CodeIgniter like wordpress. Does anyone have some links or tips to share with me on this matter?

I would like to create several functions that I can call from those php template pages like in wordpress. For example to display the comments from an item or loop through something, or even a tag_could.

the views folder would containt the different template folders & files.

and yes there is smarty, but no I don't want to use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out

http://www.williamsconcepts.com/ci/codeigniter/libraries/template/index.html

Template is right for you if:

- You feel like using views can be clunky, especially when "embedding" views.
- You don't like calling header, footer, and other global views from every Controller method.
- You prefer having one "master template" that can be changed for any controller in order to meet unique application design needs.
- You don't want to drastically alter the way you interface controllers and views.
- You like clear, thorough documentation on par with CodeIgniter's User Guide.

Answer (score 11):

Have a look at my [Template library](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/code/codeigniter-template). It supports modules, themes, partials and layouts so you can create one main layout for each theme then have modular views if you wish.

While you are not a fan of Smarty, you might be interested in trying [Dwoo](http://dwoo.org/). They are both very similar but Dwoo has the advantage of not sucking major donkey balls, which is Smarty's main downfall. I have written an [extension for the CodeIgniter Parser library](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/code/codeigniter-dwoo) to get it to use Dwoo, which integrates perfectly with my Template library.

Between the two you can make pretty powerful, theme-able MVC applications.

Comment: one up on phil's ive based my own off his and its worked great

Comment: Mine not good enough for you Tom? heh :-p If you feel like contributing the changes back I am always happy to merge or accept github forks.

Comment: thanks :D I'm using the template library that sylvio posted because he commented sooner and I allready jumped into the code but after looking at the link you provided I'll make sure to have a look at your template library as well and see which one works better as I will be selling this script I'm making I need it to be easy to customize.

many thanks for your response